# solution of laplace equation in 3 dimension by speration of variables covers all possible solutions?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, spherical-harmonics

The usual procedure to solve the Laplace equation in 3 dimensional space is to switch to spherical coordinates, use the seperation of variables approach, which eventually leads to the well-known spherical harmonics. But how do we know that we have found all possible solutions by that procedure?

By using the seperation of variables approach, we made the assumption of $$f(r,\theta,\phi) = f_1(r)f_2(\theta)f_3(\phi).$$ How do we know that there is not a function $f^*$ that does not meet this assumption but still is a solution to the laplace equation in 3d?

Additionally, do not the spherical harmonics form a complete orthogonal base in the space of square-integrable functions? Therefore actually "all" square-integrable functions are solutions of the Laplace equation in 3d?

Comment: Clearly most solutions are not of that form. The point is that you have lots of separated solutions, and can form more general solutions by taking *linear combinations* of them.

Comment: Can you give me an example of a solution that is not of that form?

Comment: @metuk There are lots of examples. $f(r,\theta,\phi)=r+\theta$ satisfies $\nabla^2 f=0$. (Here I am taking $\theta$ as the *azimuthal* angle.)

Comment: But it is a combination of the solutions $f(r,\theta,\phi) = r$ and $f(r,\theta,\phi) = \theta$, which are both of the form $f(r,\theta,\phi) = f(r)f(\theta)f(\phi)$. So to be more precise, I am looking for an example that is not a linear combination of a solution of the form $f(r,\theta,\phi) = f(r)f(\theta)f(\phi)$, but still fulfills the laplace equation.